# Keras 2D output

Tags: keras

I need to make a model that takes as input a 2D binary matrix: (37,10) for instance and return a real 2D matrix of the same shape as the input one. I erote this code but I am not sure what **X** (in the output layer) should be equal to.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation='linear',input_shape=(37,10)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(X,activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Please let me know if you think my model is correct as defined and what to write instead of **X**

Thank you

Comment: using dense is a bad choice for 2d data.

Answer (score 3):

I updated your code to get shape of output same as input. We need to add `Flatten` and `Reshape` layer at the start and end of the model. In simple, `X` should be equal to the number of elements in the input_shape.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten,Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

input_shape=(37,10)
num_elm =input_shape[0]*input_shape[1]
model=Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(num_elm, activation='linear'))
model.add(Reshape(input_shape))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 370)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 32)                11872     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 32)                1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 370)               12210     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 37, 10)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 25,138
Trainable params: 25,138
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to NN and what I understand from your solution is like that you transformed the input to 1D and then you retransformed th output to 2D again. right?

Answer (score 0):

`X` will be 10 even though using FC layers for 2-d data may not be very suitable in the first place, also you're sure the metrics will be accuracy.

Here's your model with the correct output shape.

Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation='linear',input_shape=(37,10)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(lr=.001),metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 37, 32)            352       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 37, 32)            1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 37, 10)            330       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,738
Trainable params: 1,738
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. yes the metric should not be accuracy since I am working on a regression problem. The problem I am working on has a 2D input, but it is not an image and according to what I read, if we can change the order of the rows or the columns without affecting the meaning of the input (not like with an image), then we should not use the Conv2D  layer. is it right? and is there another solution (type of layer ) to use in this case? thanks again.

Comment: What kind of data is that? Is there any spatial relation in the matrix?

Comment: No, there is no spatial relation. it is an assignment problem so in the input matrix I have some assignment of tasks to agents: if there is an assgnment the value is 1 otherwise it is 0. and for the output (labels) I put the same value of the   objective function in the corresponding assgnment. What I expect from the model is to get the prediction of the value function for every possible assgnment of tasks to agents. Here we consider that no restrictions exists on the number of tasks assigned to agents.

Comment: Then this might work too, you don't need Conv2D specifically.