# ValueError issue when using LSTM layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build up a very simple LSTM structure using padding and masking to learn how to train time series data. Suppose I have two people's blood value information per month. For the first person, I only have seven months of data, wheares, for the next person, I only have four months of data. Lastly, I select -100 as my padding value to complete the sequences.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Masking

#each column represent a different blood value. 
xPad =  np.array([[
  [  0.4654949,    0.06225133],
  [ -0.48630088,   0.97063685],
  [ -0.23714237,  1.07598604],
  [ -0.94519772,   0.76515959],
  [ -0.81456729,   1.05963647],
  [  0.60236851,   1.26799774],
  [  1.89095161,   1.02534057]],

 [[ -1.76505643,   0.61171791],
  [  2.00335928,  -0.02941931],
  [ -1.58293956,  -0.02671103],
  [  1.57166957,  -0.39450184],
  [-100,         -100        ],
  [-100,         -100        ],
  [-100,         -100        ]]])
```

Suppose I would like to estimate whether the person will be low weight, medium weight, and high weight. That's why I also have this information for each month per person as shown below. For the second person, I fill the missing months with zero vector. For instance, `[0,0,1]` implies that the person within that spesific month is high weight.

```
y = np.array([
    [[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0]],
    [[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
    ])
```

Then, I create my network using tensorflow.

```
special_value= -100
seq_len = 7
dim = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=special_value, input_shape=(seq_len, dim)))
model.add(LSTM(5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))
model.fit(xPad, y, epochs=10, batch_size=2)
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong here. I would appreciate any help.

```
Dimensions must be equal, but are 7 and 2 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/Cast, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [2,7,3], [2,3]
```

Comment: What is the full error you're getting?

Comment: @thushv89 I updated my post and included the error message. I am confused about how ````tensorflow```` knows each three-dim array inside array ````y```` corresponds to a label. In the sample codes provided online, ````y```` is only defined for the entire time series one time. For my case, I have a label at each time step.

Comment: Would you mind giving your input data shape?

Comment: It is ````(2,7,2)````( where I have two data instances, seven time sequences, and two dimensions (features). In ````y````, I have three different labels for each time sequence.

Comment: Then on your output layer (dense one) you should have 2 outputs not three. Try changing this model.add(Dense(2))

Comment: I have three labels as explained in the post. If I create the last layer with two neurons, how do I know whether the person is low, medium or high weight in the coming time period?

Comment: Using `Dense` layer for 2D output value is a bad choice. Hope this link will help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418046/keras-2d-output)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can make your problem go away by changing

```
model.add(LSTM(5))
```

to,

```
model.add(LSTM(5, return_sequences=True))
```

Here's an expansion on the answer.

You got `xPad` of shape `[2, 7, 2]` and `y` of shape `[2, 7, 3]`. So it seems you are trying to predict `y` for **every time step** of `xPad`. Then what the error says is,

It has an LSTM that outputs only the **last** state of it, but your `y` is for all of the time steps (which are incompatible). `return_sequences=True` outputs the states for all of the time steps, which makes your `y` compatible with the output of the model.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749404/how-to-connect-lstm-layers-in-keras-repeatvector-or-return-sequence-true/51757012#51757012) shows what `return_sequences=True` does.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I actually want to predict ````y```` only for the last time period, however, I do know the ````y```` for all the previous time periods. Do you think that what I am doing is wrong then?

Comment: If you just need to predict the last timestep, you can keep the model as is and only use the last timestep of `y` (i.e. y[:, -1, :]) as the label. However, I can see that the label changes over time in the data. So you might see the model underperforming this way. 

The other option is to use my solution and make predictions for all time steps and only use the last prediction in that.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the previous labels as a feature? So that the model actually use them during training.